# Getting/Setting UWP Xaml WebView Zoom and Scroll Positions?

Tags: xaml, webview, uwp

In a Xaml UWP app, is it possible to get and set the WebView's Zoom and scroll positions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

You can use the [WebView.InvokeScriptAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) to execute the specified script function from the currently loaded HTML.

For scrolling to position, it is simple for example like this:

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string ScrollToposition = @"window.scrollTo(0,200);";
    await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { ScrollToposition });
}
```

For zoom function, it's a different story, you will need the have a full control of the web page. For this scenario, you can refer to the sample [How to zoom in/out the content in WebView in universal Windows apps](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-zoom-inout-the-5a42229b).